# How can I enable my community to flag (report) bad content on my site?

Tags: 7, flags

I got a dev site with Drupal 7.

I want to give my visitors the ability to flag (report) content that is abusive or problematic.
I tried using the [Flag](http://drupal.org/project/flag) module together with the [Flag Abuse](http://drupal.org/project/flag_abuse) module.

The Flag Abuse module can reset (remove) the flag/reports only one time; after that, it removes the Flag/Report and the Reset Button (for administrators). That is very bad, and totally not practical. Imagine a bad user creates 2 accounts, adds content with account "A," and reports that content with account "B"; you as administrator will check the content, see whats wrong, fix it and press the reset button. After that, the report and reset buttons are gone. So the bad user can edit his content and nobody can report it to administrators. So that module is pretty useless.

Do you know a similar module to solve this problem? Or do you know how I can fix the reset button? I have managed to do the reset button appear multiple times, but I get a lot of errors: The button only works every 3rd time that is pressed.

Comment: What you report here seems a bug of the module. Did you report this in the project queue on drupal.org?

Comment: Its not a bug. The module desctipion says "When that user clicks this it resets all of the abuse flags on that object and makes to that it cannot be flagged as abuse anymore."  Source URL : http://drupal.org/project/flag_abuse

Comment: Uhmmm… It's not what I would expect from the module, considering the scenario you described, which is a plausible scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made my own solution. Using Flags, Rules and Views.

I have also uploaded a video Tutorial on youtube explaining how to flag content and create a "Reset" action on content edition.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b5xieuVf01E&list=PL1A89955CCEB73A09&feature=plpp